# Gmail workspace add-on Mobile app has no back navigation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

We have Gmail Workspace add-on that is used on both the Gmail Web app and Gmail Mobile app.

For some reason when running in the Gmail Mobile app there is no back navigation available.  The below screen shot shows the navigation on the Web app.

[image]

But this is not available on the Mobile app?

[image]

I can't see this difference documented anywhere.  Is there something we are not setting to enable this?

Also in addition to the back navigation not being available we get an error whenever we try and set the navigation via app script.

For example the following:

```
cs.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(cs.newNavigation().popCard()).build()
```

gives the error on Mobile app only -

> failed to complete your action because the add-on will be in a bad
> state

[image]

Is this behaviour to be expected?  Is there some other approach to controlling navigation on Gmail Mobile that we are not aware of?

Comment: Put the navigation into your app

Comment: @Cooper have tried that - and have been getting the error 'failed to complete your action because the add-on will be in a bad state' when we try to pop the card

Comment: I'd have to see the code to help you

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem...  In case somebody else experiences it.

In my code - the issue is caused when an invoked function returns a card as in the following snippet

```
function loadStackCard() {
  var emailCard = CardService.newCardBuilder().setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('STACK CARD'))
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('GO BACK')
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('goBack')))).build();         
    return emailCard;
}
```

But when I push the card onto the navigation stack it works on Mobile

```
function loadStackCard() {
  var emailCard = CardService.newCardBuilder().setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('STACK CARD'))
    .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(CardService.newTextButton().setText('GO BACK')
    .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('goBack')))).build(); 
    nav = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(emailCard) ;
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(nav).build();
}
```